# Please can someone explain what this DENSE_RANK line is showing me?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view that is running very slowly and have deduced that the DENSE_RANK function is causing it to run slowly.
I have a line of code in a view that is this:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATEADD(DD, -DAY(CONVERT(DATE, Full_Date, 103)) + 1, CONVERT(DATE, Full_Date, 103)) DESC) AS MonthRank
```

Please could someone explain to me what this is doing?

Could someone provide me with a potential alternative to this to make the query run quicker?

Comment: `DATEADD(DD, -DAY(CONVERT(DATE, Full_Date, 103)) + 1, CONVERT(DATE, Full_Date, 103))` looks like a fairly convoluted way of getting the start of the month. Version of SQL Server? If 2022 `DATETRUNC(MONTH, Full_Date)` can potentially use an index better. Though you should show us the whole query so we can see the context and definition of tables and views

Comment: I'm guessing it's doing an equivalent of calculating first day of month for every date. It's a way of grouping date by year + month combination. As to what to do to improve it, remove the dense rank from the view and calculate it yourself in the query perhaps?

Comment: (1) Is `Full_Date` stored as `VARCHAR` or similar instead of a proper `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `DATETIME2` type? That would be your first problem - you need to fix the schema. (2) f not text, avoid date-to-text-to-date conversions. The `DATETRUNC()` mentioned above by @MartinSmith above is preferred for SQL Server 2022 and later. For earlier versions you can use `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Full_Date), 0)` or `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Full_Date), MONTH(Full_Date), 1)`. (3) Do you really need `DENSE_RANK()`? If used just for grouping, why not just use the calculated start-of-month instead?

Comment: Another possibility to consider is that the dense_rank() is not the real issue, but the initial filtering of the source data is lacking. If you have a table with many years of data, but only need to query data over a few months, properly filtering your data up front is a must. (1) Make dure your dates are properly typed (not as text). (2) Ensure that you have an index on that date (and other key filter columns). (3) When filtering a date range, **do not apply first-of-month calculations to the date column**. Instead precalculate the start and end date/time range, and filter for that range.

Answer (score 0):

**An Explanation**

Convert Full_Date to a Date data type: `CONVERT(DATE, Full_Date, 103)`

Subtract the day of the month from the date in Full_Date and add 1. The net result is to give the first day of the month of the date in Full_Date:

```
DATEADD(
  DD, 
  -DAY(CONVERT(DATE, Full_Date, 103)) + 1, 
  CONVERT(DATE, Full_Date, 103)
)
```

Sort the first-of-month dates in descending order.

Use DENSE_RANK to assign an integer rank to each month.

So, these dates:

```
15/12/2023
2/12/2023
16/11/2023
31/1/2023
9/10/2022
```

Would be converted to:

```
1/12/2023
1/12/2023
1/11/2023
1/1/2023
1/10/2023
```

And get these ranks (dense gives identical ranks to same values):

```
1
1
2
3
4
```

**Some Suggestions**

- Persist the Full_Date column as a Date in the first place, so that it doesn't need to be converted in the view. Either change the data type of the Full_Date column or create a new column with the right data type.
- If you can, store the data in the table in Full_Date order (via clustered index *if* this is appropriate in your environment)
- Assuming downstream processes still need the rank of 'most recent month', then try this instead:

```
DENSE_RANK() 
  OVER (ORDER BY EOMONTH(Full_Date) DESC) 
AS MonthRank
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "store the data in the table in Full_Date order". SQL Server tables do not have a defined order. They do have primary keys and indexes, one of which can be clustered. Are you suggesting defining a Full_Date index as the clustered index? Such a design facet may optimize one access route at the cost of others.

Comment: No point messing with arithmetic, can just do `OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(Full_Date) DESC, MONTH(Full_Date) DESC)` or just `OVER (ORDER BY EOMONTH(Full_Date) DESC)`

Comment: @Charlieface These seem to be working the best. They have really sped up the execution of the view. Quick question - would you know how to find the Quarters?

Comment: @EAsh On SQL Server 2022 `OVER (ORDER BY DATETRUNC(quarter, Full_Date) DESC)` otherwise `OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(Full_Date) DESC, DATEPART(quarter, Full_Date) DESC)`